# Beeware WebView Site launch issue

Tags: python, webview, beeware

I am trying to make a simple `WebView`-type app that supports opening only one URL viz `https://14.139.222.78:443`. But on loading the `mainbox` it is showing something like `Unacceptable TLS certificate`. An MWE of `{APPNAME}/src/{APPNAME}/app.py` is attached hereby:

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW


class APPMAIL(toga.App):

    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(flex=1, direction="column"))
        webview = toga.WebView(user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

        webview.url = "https://14.139.222.78:443"

        main_box.add(webview)        
        
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

def main():
    return APPMAIL()
```

If you open the url on Browser, it perfectly launches. I don't know why it does not support `WebView`. I want the the same browser content in this Beeware App.

---

The reason why Browser is opening the URL and WebView is not can be checked comparing the result from [Link1](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=mail.isical.ac.in/) and [Link2](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.isical.ac.in/). So the certificate chain is failing to reach the root certificate in case of Taga WebView (Ubuntu 22, macOS is working fine as reported by @mhsmith), but browser is maintaining some additional information to validate such broken chain even if not provided by the user.

Thus the question reduces to whether such URLs (ie URLs with broken Certificate-chain) can be launched using Toga WebView in Ubuntu 22. If so how?

Comment: With a rush browsing online, I found a concept of bypassing SSL/TLS Certification error in Android WebView (https://youtu.be/JNtFTwZyy-4). Does there exist any in BeeWare Yoga WebView?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to load that URL, my browser also gives a TLS error, because the server's certificate is for `*.isical.ac.in`.

Opening an HTTPS URL via an IP address is unlikely to work, because CAs don't usually issue SSL certificates for IP addresses. If it did work in your browser, it's probably because you'd previously told the browser to ignore SSL errors for that address.

Try changing the URL to one that uses a domain name rather than an IP address.

Comment: The domain name for the particular IP Address 14.139.222.78:443 is `mail.isical.ac.in`. I tried both the ways but it flashes same error under the Beeware App. However any browser like Chrome or Firefox can open it right away.

Comment: With Toga 0.3.1 on macOS, if I take your example and change the URL to `https://mail.isical.ac.in`, the page loads fine. If that doesn't work for you, please create an issue on the Toga GitHub page, and remember to mention which platform you're running on.

Comment: You'll probably also want to add `style=Pack(flex=1)` to the WebView, to make it fill the whole window.

Comment: I am using named domain address while building the App. But didn't name it here.  And  Thanks for sharing the environment you are using and confirming the execution. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and Toga 0.3.1.

Comment: As you have correctly detected the Toga GitHub issue #2120, I think if `requests` is giving some switch like `verify`, there should be some handle in Toga too. As you are reporting macOS is supporting openning a URL while Ubuntu is failing, till maturity I guess Toga should introduce such `verify` switch.